# find $u$, $v$, $w$ such that $u \times (v \times w)\neq (u \times v) \times w$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Can someone help with this question?

Let $\times$ denote the cross product of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Find $u$, $v$, $w$ such that $u \times (v \times w)$ is different from $(u \times v) \times w$?

I don't know how to start, Thanks!

Comment: See Jacob identity

Comment: Hint: for any vector $v$ we have $v\times v = 0$.

Comment: Just start by trying random vectors. I bet there's a (counter)example using various $\pm e_i$ for your vectors.

Comment: I've edited the Question.  Please review to check that I did not unintentionally change your meaning (you can rollback the edit if I did).

Answer (score 3):

Let $i,j,$ and $k$ be the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then
$$i\times (i\times j) = i\times k = -j$$
$$(i\times i)\times j = 0\times j = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

**Jacob Identity**

$$a\times (b\times c)+b\times(c \times a) +c\times(a \times b)=0$$

$$a\times(b\times c)=-c\times (a \times b) $$ iff$$b\times(c\times a)=0$$

**Now note** $-c\times (a \times b)=(a \times b)\times c$.

**then**
$$a\times(b\times c)=(a \times b) \times c$$

So we mustn't have $$b\times (c \times a) =0$$

Or as you wrote all vectors which do not satisfy $v\times (w \times u)=0$.

Comment: What part dont you get (or should I repeat the same thing and hope it works)

Comment: You'll have to remain concrete in your objection to help me understand where a problem is. My answer rigorously defines the set which was asked for?

Comment: $$\{ \{u,v,w\} \ : u,v,w \in \Bbb R^3 \ \cap \ v\times (w \times u) \neq 0 \}$$

Comment: @I guess I didnt try and find a single one which maybe was the question to just find one such example? Is that your issue you couldn't find words for?

Comment: Well there is $c\times (a\times b)$ type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58839/discussion-between-marshal-craft-and-pjs36).

Comment: Good point any binary operator which has "antisymmetry" or is anticommutative and has Jacob property will have same property. Wikipedia is useful but I will say that I did cover Jacob identity in undergrad electrodynamics using standard textbook introduction to electrodynamics third revision.

Comment: By Griffiths which is a standard and very good in my opinion as well as is in my opinion very very vector calulus orientated as opposed to a modern science text. Very good I recommend really a course with it to a math major even though it is physics!

Comment: By Griffiths which is a standard and very good in my opinion as well as is in my opinion very very vector calulus orientated as opposed to a modern science text. Very good I recommend really a course with it to a math major even though it is physics! Also my instructor Prf. Kieth Earl was amazing too funny guy. Ounce in refering to theorem would say that is variables $sds$ not to be confused with students for democratic society.. >.<

Comment: Griffiths was funny too also his quantum mechanics text which is great also. Though a funny anecdote escapes my memory at this time, I recommend them all.